# Index Column With Exception - POWER BI / DAX / M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column with unique Values of Countries, I just need to to create a index column.

The problem is that in this column I have a "country" that is "Other", I need this country to appears at the end.

```
let
    Source = Table.SelectColumns(Orders,"Country"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source),
    #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "CountryId", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Add Index"
```

"Add index but when/with Country="Other" put at the final.

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of would be to add a new column that replaces the index for `"Other"` (and then delete the old index column).

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Add Index", "NewIndex", each
    if [Country] = "Other" then List.Max(#"Add Index"[CountryId]) + 1 else [CountryId]
)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Can you adapt the code if I need to use more than condition? Example: If "Other" or "Miss"

Comment: You could insert an additional clause like `else if [Country] = "Miss" then List.Max(#"Add Index"[CountryId]) + 2` into your column definition.

Comment: Oh I understand, great. Can you please take a look to other similar problem that I have? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65145128/add-index-without-unique-values-power-bi-dax-m